# R Create test dataframe with future dates

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to create a test dataframe of future dates from another dataframe
The issue that I have is that the data is not static meaning I will never know what dates are coming in but I must predict the next 30 days
I can get yesterdays date:

```
yesterday <- tail(data$Order_Date, 1)

test <- data.frame( as.Date(this is where I get lost), Sales = NA)
```

```
DataFrame:
+---------------+--------------+
| Order_Date    | Sales        | 
+---------------+--------------+
| 10-29-20      |    50        |  
+---------------+--------------+
| 10-28-20      |    50        |   
+---------------+--------------+
| 10-27-20      |    50        |  
+---------------+--------------+
| 10-26-20      |    50        |   
+---------------+--------------+
```

What I am trying to do :

```
Test Dataframe
+---------------+--------------+
| Order_Date    | Sales        | 
+---------------+--------------+
| 10-30-20      |              |  
+---------------+--------------+
| 10-31-20      |              |   
+---------------+--------------+
| 11-01-20      |              |  
+---------------+--------------+
| 10-26-20      |              |   
+---------------+--------------+
....continues for 1 month
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `seq.Date`:

```
test <- data.frame(
    Order_Date = seq.Date(from = yesterday + 1L, by = "1 day", length.out = 30L),
    Sales = NA_real_
)
```